# How to hide a hierarchy of parent child in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a hierarchy of divs and there is a input box which has unique name attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".first > input[name='inp']").hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="first">
  First
  <div class="second">
  Second
    <label for="inp">Label Input</label>
    <input type="text" name="inp" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to hide the div *first* if it has any input child with that specific unique name.

I used this selector `input[name='inp']` for input, How do I remove the whole *first* div now, `parent().hide()` removes only the first parent.

**Note:** There are multiple divs with the same class name, so I cannot use class selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:has()` selector, selects all elements that have one or more elements inside of them, that matches the specified selector.:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".first:has(input[name='inp'])").hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="first">
  First
  <div class="second">
  Second
    <label for="inp">Label Input</label>
    <input type="text" name="inp" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

First select all inputs, then hide it's parents.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='inp']").closest('.first').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
  First 1
  <div class="second">
  Second
    <label for="inp">Label Input</label>
    <input type="text" name="inp" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="first">
  First 2
  <div class="second">
  Second
    <label for="inp">Label Input</label>
    <input type="text" name="inp" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="first">
  First 3
  <div class="second">
  Second
    <label for="inp">Label Input</label>
    <input type="text" name="inp3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Your `parent().hide()` does not work, because it selects `.second`, not `.first`. There is also `.parents()` to select all parents, so it would be `.parents().eq(1).hide()`

Comment: Does `closest` searches it from top - bottom or the other way around ?

Comment: @bhansa It searches from current element up-top to `<html>`. It also may match current element: e.g. if `name="inp" class="first"`.